# How to top-align smaller inline-block elements next to larger elements?

Tags: html, css

How can I top-align inline-block elements? What I mean is how can I make inline-block elements appear aligned from the top of the largest element instead of from the bottom. I have made a fiddle to illustrate it:
https://jsfiddle.net/shzyku6u/

When you expand the window wide enough, the 3 smaller blue images appear inline from the bottom of the larger blue image. I would like them to appear from the top of the large, blue image - if it's possible.

[image: How to top-align smaller inline-block elements next to larger elements?]

Here is the HTML/CSS from the Fiddle:

```css
.topwrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
}
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
}
.listitem {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topwrapper">

  <div class="block">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fd/000080_Navy_Blue_Square.svg/480px-000080_Navy_Blue_Square.svg.png" width="400" height="400" class="bigimage">
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="listitem">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fd/000080_Navy_Blue_Square.svg/200px-000080_Navy_Blue_Square.svg.png" height="100" width="100">
      </li>
      <li class="listitem">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fd/000080_Navy_Blue_Square.svg/200px-000080_Navy_Blue_Square.svg.png" height="100" width="100">
      </li>
      <li class="listitem">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fd/000080_Navy_Blue_Square.svg/200px-000080_Navy_Blue_Square.svg.png" height="100" width="100">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both of the `.block` sibling elements have a `display` of `inline-block`, the `vertical-align` property will be respected. Just add `vertical-align: top`:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/gksh2ur9/)

```
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Oh boy, I spend literary hours trying to figure it out, and you solved it in a minute. Thanks! While searching the site, I came across vertical-align, but I placed it inside the <li> instead of the "blocks".